# Get full size facebook picture profile in Cognito user pool attribute

Tags: facebook, amazon-cognito

How can I get facebook full-size profile picture in Cognito User Pool attribute mappings.

I have mapped the Facebook attribute "picture" to Cognito User pool attribute "Picture" but the problem is that facebook is returning a picture of 50x50. I don't know how to specify the resolution in Cognito.

picture returned by facebook:

```
{ 
   data: {
     height: 50,
     is_silhouette: false,
     url: <URL of profile picture>,
     width: 50 
    }
}
```

Comment: did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Nope, I couldn't find a way to get profile picture in full size. What I did is mapping "cover" attribute (facebook) into "Picture" attribute (user pool).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this. It's a bit of effort but it works.

1. In cognito map the `access_token` to some unused user pool attribute. I mapped it to `profile`
2. Add a post confirmation lambda trigger. The lamdba should receive an event which will have a user pool attribute `profile` set to the facebook access token of the logged in user. The lambda should then;

- Use this access token to get a profile picture of any size you want form the Facebook api like [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/401988904382290/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dpicture.width(800).height(800)&version=v11.0).
- Use [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUpdateUserAttributes.html) cognito endpoint to update the user attributes with the profile picture returned from Facebook. You can also remove the `profile` attribute as you probably don't want to actually store the users Facebook access token in cognito.